# Using pooledMapConcurrentlyN in polysemy

Tags: haskell, haskell-polysemy, effect-systems

I'm currently playing around with Polysemy, rewriting a small toy project of mine to get used to it. I'm stumbling upon a piece of code that uses [`pooledMapConcurrentlyN`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unliftio-0.2.13/docs/UnliftIO-Async.html#v:pooledMapConcurrentlyN), so basically a parallel version of traverse with bounded concurrency.

I can strip my example down to this:

```hs
foo :: Sem r Int
foo = do
  res <- pooledMapConcurrentlyN 3 action (["foo", "bar", "baz"] :: [String])
  pure $ sum res

action :: String -> Sem r Int 
action = pure. length
```

This doesn't compile because there's no instance for `MonadUnliftIO (Sem r)`. It does compile when I use `traverse`, but I'm looking for a concurrent version. I'm not sure which way I should go now.

I see the following options:

- Implement a `MonadUnliftIO (Sem r)` instance. I see that there were some discussions about adding/implementing such an instance in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/polysemy-research/polysemy/issues/73). However, it's not clear to me whether it's a good idea to do so.
- Using something other than `pooledMapConcurrentlyN` that gives me an equivalent behavior. I know that there's `parTraverse` from the [par-dual](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/par-dual-0.1.0.0/docs/Control-ParDual-Class.html#v:parTraverse) package, but that would require a `ParDual` instance. The [`parallel`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parallel) package could make a solution possible as well, but I'm not familiar with that so I can't tell if it's possible.
- Model the parallel traverse as an effect. I tried it, but I couldn't manage to get an implementation for the effect. The effect definition I tried looks like this:

```hs
data ParTraverse m a where
  TraverseP :: (Traversable t) => Int -> (a -> m b) -> t a -> ParTraverse m (t b)
```

I'm not really familiar yet with neither GADTs nor Polysemy, so it's possible that I'm missing something obvious here.

---

**EDIT:** As pointed out in the answer below, the most appropriate solution is to model this as an effect and handle the concurrency in the effect interpretation as opposed to the business logic. This means that I'm looking for a higher order effect (?) similar to the `ParTraverse` effect above:

```hs
data ParTraverse m a where
  TraverseP :: (Traversable t) => (a -> m b) -> t a -> ParTraverse m (t b)

makeSem ''ParTraverse

parTraverseToIO :: (Member (Embed IO) r) => Sem (ParTraverse ': r) a -> Sem r a
parTraverseToIO = interpretH $ \case
  TraverseP f ta -> do
    _something
```

I'm not sure whether this type signature is correct or not (should the action have type `a -> Sem r b`? The signature for `traverse` has an `Applicative` constraint on `m`, how would I model that?)

Comment: Is the concurrent execution a part of your "business logic"? And in what way?

Comment: No, not necessarily. I'm fetching a list of things from an API and then I'd like to traverse over this list and do another API call for each of the list elements. So it's a classic example for traverse, but for performance reasons I need the concurrency.

Comment: Well, the longer I think about it, the more I have the feeling that I want an effect for traverse that then can be interpreted concurrently, if necessary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for the `ParTraverse` implementation, this is what I replied over on github, for a version specialized to `[]` for `t`:

```hs
pooledMapConcurrently :: Member (Final IO) r => Int -> (a -> Sem r b) -> [a] -> Sem r [Maybe b]
pooledMapConcurrently num f ta =
  ...

data ParTraverse m a where
  TraverseP :: (a -> m b) -> [a] -> ParTraverse m [b]

makeSem ''ParTraverse

parTraverseToIO :: (Member (Final IO) r) => InterpreterFor ParTraverse r
parTraverseToIO =
  interpretH \case
   TraverseP f ta -> do
     taT <- traverse pureT ta
     fT <- bindT f
     tb <- raise (parTraverseToIO (pooledMapConcurrently 1 fT taT))
     ins <- getInspectorT
     pureT (catMaybes (inspect ins <$> catMaybes tb))
```

Some explanations for the combinators used inside `interpretH`, where we operate in the `Tactical` environment:

- Since we're dealing with a function `a -> m b`, where `m` is instantiated to `Sem rInitial` inside the interpreter, we have to use `bindT` to get a function that is something like `f a -> Sem r (f b)`, with `f` being the monadic state of the interpreters.
- We can't run `pooledMapConcurrently` on the `Sem rInitial` directly, because `Member (Final IO)` is only given for `r`.
- `ta` contains the input for `f`, but since we lifted that to expect `f a`, we also have to call `pureT` on each element of `ta`, using `traverse` since it is a monadic action.
- Functions produced by `bindT` (and `runT`) produce `Sem`s that still have the current effect, `ParTraverse`, at the head, because the effect has to be interpreted within the wrapped `Sem` (passed in as `a -> m b`). This even allows to use a different interpreter for the inner program. In our case, we simply run `parTraverseToIO` on the result of `f` again. After that, we have to lift this `Sem` back into the `Tactical` environment (which is just another effect at the head), so we use `raise`.
- Since our lifted `f` produces `f (Maybe b)` as result, we need to unpack this in order to get the return type right. For that, we can use the inspector, which transforms `f` to `Maybe`, giving us `Maybe (Maybe b)`, which we can then flatten into a list.

---

For completeness, here's the implementation of `pooledMapConcurrently`, written by KingoftheHomeless:

```hs
pooledMapConcurrently :: (Member (Final IO) r, Traversable t) => Int -> (a -> Sem r b) -> t a -> Sem r (t (Maybe b))
pooledMapConcurrently i f t = withWeavingToFinal $ \s wv ins ->
  (<$ s) <$> pooledMapConcurrentlyIO i (\a -> ins <$> wv (f a <$ s)) t
```

Answer (score 1):

Then I would try:

0. Don't do the concurrency as an effect in your business logic
1. Use [pooledMapconcurrentlyIO](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unliftio-0.2.13/docs/UnliftIO-Internals-Async.html#v:pooledMapConcurrentlyIO) + embed in your interpreter

So you would have something like this

```hs
data GetThings m a where
  GetThings :: [InfoToFetchThing] -> GetThings m [Thing]

runGetThingsConcurrently :: Member (Embed IO) r => Sem (GetThings ': r) a -> Sem r a
runGetThingsConcurrently = interpret \case
  GetThings infos -> do
  ...
  embed $ pooledMapConcurrentlyIO 42 <fetch-action> infos
```

Ofcourse, you can also customise this a lot - have a `Traversable` instead of a list, pass in `<fetch-action>` as an argument to the interpreter, pass in how many threads you want as an argument to you interpreter, etc.

Edit: since the action to be executed is also required to be in Sem r, and not in IO, you can use [withWeavingToFinal](https://github.com/polysemy-research/polysemy/issues/73#issuecomment-708170100) to (potentially) get IO out of Sem r, as described in the link.

Comment: Yes, I think that's the best way to go. However, it's a bit more complicated: The action that's called on each element of the list is itself effectful and it contains business logic. If I understand it correctly, this makes it a higher order effect? I tried it with the TraverseP effect mentioned above, where I failed to write an interpreter for. I'll update my question to make it a little more clear what I'm looking for

Comment: You don't need to put your action inside the effect - you can pass it as an argument to your interpreter, so


```
runGetThingsConcurrently :: Member (Embed IO) r => (InfoToFetchThing -> Sem r Thing) -> Sem (GetThings ': r) a -> Sem r a
```

Unfortunately, now we cycle back to the "MonadUnliftIO problem", because pooledMapConcurrentlyIO requires an IO argument

Comment: That would imply moving some of the business logic to the interpreter, right? IMHO the decision which action should be done to each element is part of the business logic.